# Force a leading 0 in a for loop

Tags: c#, winforms, for-loop

I'm currently analysing a series of numbers by using a loop as follows :-

```
using (var cmd = new DBCommand(dbConnection))
    for (double i = 10; i < 100; i++)    
    {
        Do Stuff
    }
```

Now this works as expected. I have been asked to extend the value of i to start from 00.
This means that it will loop as follows :- 00, 01, 02, 03, 04.....
This is where the issue lies as it currently analyses 0, 1, 2, 3..... dropping the leading 0.

How do I force the loop to include the leading 0?

Comment: only formatting it to a string

Comment: Do you really mean to use a double, also?

Comment: Any why do you initialize the variable to 10 and not 0?

Comment: To answer the questions:- I have a series of numbers & I analyse digits that occur at certain points in each number (ie:- in the number 178611.0986 there is no 10 but there is an 11). Initially I was only asked to look at the numbers 10 to 100, but now the powers that be have asked me to look at 00 through 100. Hence the requirement for a leading 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numbers don't have leading zeros, why should they have? You want to format a string which represents a number. You can use `"D2"` in `ToString`:

```
for(int i=0; i < 100; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("D2"));
}
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/A6sF2W)

- [**How to: Pad a Number with Leading Zeros**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048.aspx)
- [**Standard Numeric Format Strings**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

> The Decimal ("D") Format Specifier The "D" (or decimal) format
>   specifier converts a number to a string of decimal digits (0-9),
>   prefixed by a minus sign if the number is negative. This format is
>   supported only for integral types.

Answer (score 1):

A number such as as an integer or floating point number will never have a leading zero. If you really want a leading zero, then you need to use the string datatype.

Answer (score 1):

just format the number when call `ToString` method:

> > value.ToString("D2")

`D2` is the Decimal format specifier with 2 digits.
for more info check MSDN [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#DFormatString)

Answer (score 0):

Numbers are stored in a binary format internally, i.e. the number `5` will exist as `00000000000000000000000000000101` in memory (not taking the big/little endian issue into account). `5` is just a litteral used in the C# code that does not exist at runtime.

If you need a special formatting of a number, convert it to a string.

```
int i = 5;
string s = i.ToString("00"); // ==> "05"
```

Also use integer values as loop variable; you need integers anyway. Floating point numbers tend to have values like `4.999999999999` instead of exactly `5` when they result from calculations, possibly making a loop loop once too much.

```
for (int i = 10; i < 100; i++) {
   string s = i.ToString("00");
   // Do stuff with s
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to add a leading `0` to an int, so you will have to use a string.

```
var stringNumbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(i => i.ToString("D2"));
foreach (var stringNumber in stringNumbers)
{
    // Do Stuff
}
```